# How to enable "Password" OAuth2 in OroCommerce 4.2 for mobile app

Tags: oauth-2.0, orocommerce

Using Postman's authorization tool, I can successfully authenticate a frontend user using client_id and and client_secret using OAuth2's "client_credential" token type, but the password type does not work as documented here: https://doc.oroinc.com/api/authentication/oauth-password/
I'm using a freshly installed 4.2.1 instance on GCP. Is there some way to enable password authentication, or do we have to create an OAuth app for each Customer User so we have per-user auth?

Answer (score 1):

No, you should not use a separate OAuth application per customer user (except client credentials grant type). But you should use a separate OAuth application per grant type.
In your case, you have to add [Storefront OAuth Applications](https://doc.oroinc.com/user/back-office/system/storefront-oauth-app/) with the "Password" grant type and then, beside client_id and  client_secret, pass username, password, and grant_type with the value set to "password". Example of a request you can find in this [article](https://doc.oroinc.com/api/authentication/oauth-password/).